# I get following error with running bundle install . I installed railsinstaller-3.2.1.exe from railsinstaller.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gem::InstallError: nio4r requires Ruby version >= 2.3.
An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '2.5.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: did you run successfully this command in console? gem install nio4r -v '2.5.2'

Comment: yes i run this command too

Comment: and result of that command is okay? no errors?

Comment: yes i get error

Comment: what is the error produced with that command?